# JSP: Why do I get 0 instead of null in EL variable?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, el

In servlet I do:

```
request.setAttribute("field-message", "Message");
```

In JSP I do:

```
<p>${field-message}</p>
```

I see 0 instead of "Message" in result HTML file.

What should I do to get "Message" shown there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p>${field-message}</p>
```

This is the difference between two attributes: "field" and "message". Both are nulls, so the difference is zero...

Either you choose another name for your attribute, or you use the construct `<p>${requestScope['field-message']}</p>`